# Adding a Spatialite 2.3.1 layer in QGIS 3: invalid layer

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I am running QGIS 3.0.3 and I am trying to add a Spatialite layer from this link

http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.1/test-2.3.zip

The program says that it is an invalid layer and that it can't be opened. I've tried different ways to opening this file.
I got this link from a course held in Udemy.
He is running QGIS 2.0.3, and I am wondering if that could be the reason for the error.

Comment: Don't bother to play with databases which are created with so old SpatiaLite versions if the database does not contain valuable data. Current SpatiaLite version is 4.4. SpatiaLite has tools for updating old databases to work with new versions but I would just find test data that is created with version 4.x.